# How to convert string of PHP code which is passed as plain text from database, to actual code which run processes?

Tags: php

The code is saved to database from plain textarea and stored exactly as `[php]echo $clientMenu;[/php]` then read into the document by a process. However the value is either rendered as plain text or not shown because the tags are being converted to comments `<!--?php $clientMenu; ?-->`, and I suspect the latter result is due to the parent application which is **WISECP** using method `remove_noise()` of class **simple_html_dom** (https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/docs/1.9/index.html) to block the output for security and I haven't figured a method to override it.

[image: screen shot]

I tried using `eval()` and the return is just `echo ;`

### My coding to process the string and output as functional PHP

```php
private static function codeblock($codeblock)
{
    if( preg_match_all('#\[php\](.*?)\[\/php\]#is', $codeblock, $phpcode, PREG_SET_ORDER) ) {
        foreach($phpcode as $php) {
            $code = '<?php '.$php[1].' ?>';
            $codeblock = str_replace($php[0], $code, $codeblock);
        }
    }
    
    return $codeblock;
}
```

The value is passed to the output method to render in the HTML document
`echo wcp::htmlRender()->head;` The data for `$clientMenu` is already within the PHP file where the HTML is rendered.

All efforts to get the process to work have failed and I am at wits end after too many hours. I would certainly appreciate any assistance.

---

**edit**

The reason for the comment result in the HTML document is due to the output being written in the page as rendered HTML and that's not the intent.

I used `eval()` (yes I know it is evil) and realize that the PHP variable is being evaluated but is returning empty. So clearly is not associating with the stored value. What is the alternative to `eval()` to parse coding string as functional PHP

String from DB `[php]$clientMenu[/php]`

```php
private static function codeblock($codeblock)
{
    if( preg_match_all('#\[php\](.*?)\[\/php\]#is', $codeblock, $phpcode, PREG_SET_ORDER) ) {
        foreach($phpcode as $php) {
            eval("\$da = \"$php[1]\";");

            $codeblock = str_replace($php[0], $da, $codeblock);
        }
    }
    
    return $codeblock;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

html_entity_decode function will help you with conversion to the actual code.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Comment: I don't see the logic of using `html_entity_decode` since the tags are not encoded when saved to DB. They are changed at the DOM level after all processes are rendered as HTML. It doesn't work.